# VBA-Excel find and select multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

i'm writing a code and i'm stuck on this problem which i think should not bee too difficult to solve but i don't manage it.

I need my program to find all cells with a particular value and select them. But they should remain selected at the end of the sub. 
So i changed a bit a code i found on the web and wrote that:

```
Sub FindAll()
 With Worksheets(4).Range("a1:l500")
 Set c = .Find("myValue", LookIn:=xlValues)
 If Not c Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = c.Address
    Do
        Worksheets(4).Range(c.Address).Activate   
        Set c = .FindNext(c)

    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Of course it selects them in sequence but they do not remain selected, so at the end i just have the last found cell selected

Can anyone help me solve that? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213609(v=office.11).aspx) to collect the ranges into one discontiguous range then `.Select` them before leaving the sub

```
Sub FindAll()
    Dim firstAddress As String, c As Range, rALL As Range
    With Worksheets(4).Range("a1:l500")
        Set c = .Find("myValue", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Set rALL = c
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                Set rALL = Union(rALL, c)
                Worksheets(4).Range(c.Address).Activate
                Set c = .FindNext(c)

            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
        .Activate
        If Not rALL Is Nothing Then rALL.Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly, i didn't know that command. Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Glad to hear you got sorted out quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Good use of `Union`.  It pairs nicely with `Find` since you are certain that `rAll` has been `Set` before entering the loop and calling `Union`.  Avoids that annoying check where you would normally set `rAll` to the first item before trying `Union`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jeeped has already answered, using the [Union Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) will achieve what you were after.

If the range you were searching for values within was to increase, it would be more efficient to use an [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) to hold the values; you can then search the array instead of the worksheet.

Just something to think about for the future.

```
Option Explicit
Sub arrayFindAll()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim myArr() As Variant, myCells() As Integer
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, k As Integer, m As Integer
    Dim valOccurence As Integer
    Dim unionCells As Range, lookupRng As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(4)
    Set lookupRng = ws.Range("A1:L500")
    myArr = lookupRng
    valOccurence = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(lookupRng, "myValue") - 1
    ReDim myCells(0 To valOccurence, 0 To 1)

    For i = LBound(myArr, 1) To UBound(myArr, 1)
        For j = LBound(myArr, 2) To UBound(myArr, 2)
            If myArr(i, j) = "myValue" Then
                For k = 0 To UBound(myCells, 1)
                    If myCells(k, 0) = 0 Then
                        myCells(k, 0) = i
                        myCells(k, 1) = j
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next k
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Set unionCells = Cells(myCells(m, 0), myCells(m, 1))
    For m = 1 To valOccurence
        Set unionCells = Union(unionCells, Cells(myCells(m, 0), myCells(m, 1)))
    Next m
    unionCells.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect this approach is not faster than using `Find` and `Union`. Have you tested for a speed comparison?  A couple comments: I would store a reference to the `Range` and not the row/column number.  This simplifies the array to 1D and the `Union` step later.  Store the current index and drop the `For k` loop.  It's a waste to iterate when you know which spot is next.  You are likely to get a boost in performance using `SpecialCells` to reduce the large range to cells that actually have a value.  And finally, this approach does not handle the case where only 0 or 1 match is found.

Comment: Thanks @ByronWall for the tips on how it could have been improved, I appreciate it. Testing on 500 rows (which the OP wanted the search to run on), my code ran in 0.04 seconds, with Jeeped's taking 0.25 seconds. So not a noticable difference for the user. Increasing to 5000 rows of data, mine took 16.94 seconds, with Jeeped's taking 20.88 seconds. Not a huge difference..

Comment: Updating the code to include the things you mentioned above (except for using `SpecialCells` as you cannot assign this range to an array) the code now took 18.55 seconds to run against 5000 rows of data. I do appreciate your tips though :)

Comment: Very interesting.  Good call on `SpecialCells` and not returning an array.  Thanks for reporting the numbers.  Out of curiosity, how many "hits" did you include in the 500/5000 rows?  And how many columns in the `UsedRange`?  Still `A:L`?

Comment: Yeah, there was continuous data in columns `A:L`. There were 2499 matching values in the 5000 rows test; 249 matching values in the 500 rows test.